# Set the table column width constant regardless of the amount of text in its cells?

Tags: html, css, column-width

In my table I set the width of the first cell in a column to be `100px`.
However, when the text in one of the cell in this column is too long, the width of the column becomes more than `100px`. How could I disable this expansion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-a-html-table might help point you in the right direction

Comment: In my case not expansion happened, but the opposite: unwanted shrink of width despite of my explicit width declaration. Ridiculous!

Comment: The only correct solution to this is to use colgroup with cols in it, and set the cols width.

Comment: `table-layout:fixed;` is the solution

Answer (score 757, accepted):

I played with it for a bit because I had trouble figuring it out.

You need to set the cell width (either `th` or `td` worked, I set both) AND set the [`table-layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) to `fixed`. For some reason, the cell width seems to only stay fixed if the table width is set, too (I think that's silly but whatev).

Also, it is useful to set the `overflow` property to `hidden` to prevent any extra text from coming out of the table.

You should make sure to leave all of the bordering and sizing for CSS, too.

Ok so here's what I have:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 200px;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>header 1</th>
    <th>header 234567895678657</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</td>
    <td>data 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Here it is in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/itamark/uAKNx/)

This guy had a similar problem: [Table cell widths - fixing width, wrapping/truncating long words](https://stackoverflow.com/q/446624/534056)

Comment: Its important to notice this: "The browser will then set column widths based on the width of cells in the first row of the table", from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570154/html-table-keep-the-same-width-for-columns

Comment: It does work when the table width is not fixed. http://jsfiddle.net/lavinski/CGCFW/3/ You just need a dynamic row to take up the remaining space.

Comment: @DanielLittle alternatively you can set the table width to 1px; with `overflow: visible` for tables of dynamic size, as long as the size of the cells is fixed and overflow is visible it doesn't matter if the size of the table itself is bigger or smaller than the actual cells.

Comment: What could you do if your td has "width=30%;"?

Comment: If the table has a `width`, even using `table-layout: fixed` the columns width will not be fixed because some columns will get enlarged to fill the table width, if the sum of all columns width is less than the table width. To avoid that you need what @MitjaGustin [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30025605/2814308) below suggests. However, if you specify the width of all columns then there is no point in also specifying the table width.

Answer (score 238):

See:
http://www.html5-tutorials.org/tables/changing-column-width/

After the table tag, use the col element. you don't need a closing tag.

For example, if you had three columns:

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width:40%">
    <col style="width:30%">
    <col style="width:30%">
  </colgroup>  
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Sam you may have had some other issue overriding this such as CSS, inline style, or incorrect doctype etc..   This definitely works, its the standard way to set column styles.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the 'HTML5 way' at all. It appears that colgroup/col in html5 is only really used for marking spans. MDN makes no mention of the use of the style attribute on col tags (other than it inherits it from global attributes) and only says of bgcolor: "...use the CSS property... on the relevant <td> elements." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col.

Comment: Worked for me with table style `table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;`. Thanks!

Comment: It's not end-all/definitive, but w3schools also does not mention the use of `col` for this. It suggests the use of css applied to a `<td>` (or a `<th`>) - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_width.asp

Comment: @Hyathin Your solution worked like a charm for me (thank you) - no extra efforts required. But it may differ for others depending on their situations. Or, maybe HTML5 is more stable now in 2017.

Comment: I did originally upvote this answer BUT it's recently come to my attention that colgroups aren't that well supported and do break in versions of IE.

Comment: It actually has nothing to do with HTML5. It does have to do with CSS, and it's been supported as far back as [CSS 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns). Besides, the element itself is also HTML4

Comment: Using this along with `table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;`, and using the widths in pixels (e.g. `<col style="width: 105px">`) worked for me.

Answer (score 153):

Just add `<div>` tag inside `<td>` or `<th>` define width inside `<div>`. 
This will help you. Nothing else works.

eg.

```
<td><div style="width: 50px" >...............</div></td>
```

Comment: I combined this solution with also specifying min-width/max-width for the same pixels width just to be on the safe side. Finally it's working. I don't know why I have to run all of these extra rounds just get it really fixed, ridiculous...

Comment: Unsure of how this is better than setting that same css `style="width: 50px"` on the `<td>`

Comment: @mmcrae It's better because it works, setting width on `<td>` doesn't.

Comment: Ridiculous, but for me the easiest working solution in combination with `display:inline-block; word-break:break-word;`.

Comment: Works like a charm! Seems to be forcing the width of the "td"

Answer (score 76):

If you need one ore more fixed-width columns while other columns should resize, try setting both `min-width` and `max-width` to the same value.

Comment: This worked for me when setting the width explicitly with `table-layout: fixed;` did not.

Answer (score 45):

You need to write this inside the corresponding CSS

```
table-layout:fixed;
```

Comment: better sorround table with div tags then inside div use overflow:auto

Comment: Worked for me when I combined it with column groups: <table style="table-layout: fixed"><colgroup><col style="width: 50%"><col style="width: 50%"></colgroup><tbody>...</tbody></table>.

Comment: This Chris Coyer article explains it well: https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/

Answer (score 29):

What I do is:

1. Set the td width:

   ```
   <td width="200" height="50"><!--blaBlaBla Contents here--></td>
   ```
2. Set the td width with CSS:

   ```
   <td style="width:200px; height:50px;">
   ```
3. Set the width again as max and min with CSS:

   ```
   <td style="max-width:200px; min-width:200px; max-height:50px; min-height:50px; width:200px; height:50px;">
   ```

It sounds little bit repetitive but it gives me the desired result. To achieve this with much ease, you may need put the CSS values in a class in your style-sheet:

```
.td_size {    
  width:200px; 
  height:50px;
  max-width:200px;
  min-width:200px; 
  max-height:50px; 
  min-height:50px;
  **overflow:hidden;** /*(Optional)This might be useful for some overflow contents*/   
}
```

then:

```
<td class="td_size">
```

Place the class attribute to any `<td>` you want.

Comment: This was the only solution that seemed to work in all cases without imposing extra, potentially-unwanted restrictions.

Comment: min/max didn't worked for me

Answer (score 7):

Setting this:

```
style="min-width:100px;"
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I used this

```
.app_downloads_table tr td:first-child {
    width: 75%;
}

.app_downloads_table tr td:last-child {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget ntch-child(2) (or 3, 4  and so on)

Comment: table td nth-child(n+1) {...} will cover all but the first column

Comment: Should we set the table-layout: fixed; or display: table; for the table element in order for this td:first-child and nth-child(n) selector to work?

Answer (score 4):

As per my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613541/css-adjusting-table-cell-width/53120641#53120641), it is also possible to use a **table head** (which can be empty) and apply relative widths for each table head cell. The widths of all cells in the table body will conform to the width of their column head. Example:

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="5%"></th>
      <th width="70%"></th>
      <th width="15%"></th>
      <th width="10%"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Some text...</td>
      <td>May 2018</td>
      <td>Edit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Another text...</td>
      <td>April 2018</td>
      <td>Edit</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
  width: 600px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #999999;
}
```

**[View Result](https://codepen.io/eicksl/pen/RqbqRN)**

Alternatively, use `colgroup` as suggested in Hyathin's answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want a fixed layout, specify a class for the column to be size appropriately.

CSS:

```
.special_column { width: 120px; }
```

HTML:

```
<td class="special_column">...</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

It also helps, to put in the last "filler cell", with **width:auto**. This will occupy remaining space, and will leave all other dimensions as specified.

Answer (score 3):

Make the accepted answer respond for small screens when smaller than the fixed width.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>header 1</th>
    <th>header 234567895678657</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf</td>
    <td>data 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table{
    border: 1px solid black;
    table-layout: fixed;
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

JS Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/w9s3ebzt/

Answer (score 2):

If you have a limited access to the table, using a class or inline style could be complicated.

Alternatively your can target the first td and th child of each row (aka the first column)

The rule bellow worked for me when I tested it with `width` but didn't work with `max-width` for some reason:

```
thead, tbody tr {
            
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

tr th:first-child, tr td:first-child {
                
    width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Getting proper sizing on a table is tricky. The only approach that has really worked for me is using `table-layout: fixed;` in combination with specified widths on each `th`. And a `width: auto;` on the one column you wouldn't mind growing.

Here's an example using a classless table. A classed version would be need if you're doing some dynamic columns.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

th:first-child, th:last-child {
  background: yellow;
  width: 5ch;

}

th:first-child, th:last-child,
td:first-child, td:last-child {
  text-align: center;
}

th:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+3) {
  background: red;
  width: 20%;
}

th:nth-child(4) {
  background: blue;
  /* use this in the columns where you're not concerned with new lines */
  word-break: break-word;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
<tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
  <th>Description</th>
  <th>Age</th>
</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Smith</td>
  <td>Vivamus fermentum elit purus, eget egestas nunc convallis ac. Vestibulum faucibus dolor nunc, vitae rutrum
    mauris porta at. Ut id ante quis lectus consectetur interdum vel in leo. Ut ut convallis ipsum, quis aliquet
    erat. Maecenas ipsum dolor, rhoncus et ultrices a</td>
  <td>30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Smith</td>
  <td>Vivamus fermentum elit purus, eget egestas nunc convallis ac. Vestibulum faucibus dolor nunc, vitae rutrum
    mauris porta at. Ut id ante quis lectus consectetur interdum vel in leo. Ut ut convallis ipsum, quis aliquet
    erat. Maecenas ipsum dolor, rhoncus et ultrices a</td>
  <td>30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Smith</td>
  <td>Vivamus fermentum elit purus, eget egestas nunc convallis ac. Vestibulum faucibus dolor nunc, vitae rutrum
    mauris porta at. Ut id ante quis lectus consectetur interdum vel in leo. Ut ut convallis ipsum, quis aliquet
    erat. Maecenas ipsum dolor, rhoncus et ultrices a</td>
  <td>30</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Smith</td>
  <td>Vivamus fermentum elit purus, eget egestas nunc convallis ac. Vestibulum faucibus dolor nunc, vitae rutrum
    mauris porta at. Ut id ante quis lectus consectetur interdum vel in leo. Ut ut convallis ipsum, quis aliquet
    erat. Maecenas ipsum dolor, rhoncus et ultrices a</td>
  <td>30</td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

KAsun has the right idea. Here is the correct code...

```
<style type="text/css">
  th.first-col > div, 
  td.first-col > div {
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:100px
  }
</style>

<table>
  <thead><tr><th class="first-col"><div>really long header</div></th></tr></thead>
  <tbody><tr><td class="first-col"><div>really long text</div></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use an ::after element in the cell where I want to set a minimal width regardless of the text present, like this:

```
.cell::after {
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    display: block;
}
```

I don't have to set width on the table parent nor use table-layout.

Answer (score -4):

I found KAsun's answer works better using **vw** instead of **px** like so:

`<td><div style="width: 10vw" >...............</div></td>`

This was the only styling I needed to adjust the column width

Answer (score -5):

You don't need to set `"fixed"` - all you need is setting `overflow:hidden` since the column width is set.

Comment: Which will hide the content behind cell borders, not a good idea.