# Html table specify columns width in px does not work

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

I'm trying to make an ajax columns-resizable table, the interface works fine, but when I resize the columnns, the browser enlarges the table at max 100%, resizing eventually other columns. 
I've tried with both this two solutions but no one works well:

1.

```
min-width: 100%;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
```

with this solution, I need to resize any single column before going (if necessary) over 100%; if I enlarge only one column, for example, all the others columns are restricted, they does not maintain the original width (as I would)

2.

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

Any ideas?

Edit:
This is the relevant html code:

```
<table class="resizable" id="TabellaDati" ><thead>  <tr>
    <th id="MDT_ThID"><span>ID</span></th>
    <th id="MDT_ThText"  style="width: 146px;">Text</th>
    <th id="MDT_ThTitle"  style="width: 148px;">Title</th>
    <th id="MDT_ThCssClass"  style="width: 83px;">CssClass</th>
    <th id="MDT_ThUrl"  style="width: 92px;">Url</th>
    <th id="MDT_ThOrdine">Ordine</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody> <tr>
    <td headers="MDT_ThID">MenuAlbo</td>
    <td headers="MDT_ThText">Albo Pretorio</td>
    <td headers="MDT_ThTitle">Albo Pretorio</td>
    <td headers="MDT_ThCssClass"></td>
    <td headers="MDT_ThUrl">/AlboPretorio</td>
    <td headers="MDT_ThOrdine">2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

And the Css:

```
#TabellaDati {
    min-width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I answered a question on setting column width with css a couple of days ago. It may help to make sure that is set up correctly first.[How to set table column width..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/css-how-to-set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text/4457905#4457905)  Basically I found I needed to set the table width as well as the th/td.  After that the table-layout: fixed should work alright.

**EDIT:**
SO, I missed that you had the cell width set inline. So I loaded your markup and css and that looks great.  (I'm using Chrome)

Then I was confused what the issue was and so I also realized that this is most likely an AJAX issue.  I'm not so hot with AJAX, but I'm still checking it out.

**UPDATE:**
Is there a reason why you must use Ajax?  That is, what benefit are you gaining by using AJAX instead of plain ol' Javascript like this:

```
var colText = document.getElementById('MDT_ThText');  
function setWidth(w) {  
 colText.style.width = w + "px";  
}
```

I feel like this would be a whole world easier, and it stays well formatted with the markup and styling you have.

If you are adamant in using AJAX, please provide what your code regarding AJAX.