# make table td so it cannot enlarge

Tags: html, css

I need to make table td so it cannot enlarge. It should be square and height fixed and if there is more text then can contain a box it should stay as is and the text just go down. Hot to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think may do what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/rVDQm/

```
table tr td {
 width:400px;
 height:400px;
 background:#ccc;
 overflow:scroll;
 overflow-x:hidden;
 display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Set the table column width constant regardless of the amount of text in its cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/css-how-to-set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text)

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

Here is a jsfiddle that has some HTML changes as well as CSS changes: http://jsfiddle.net/GR4Lm/

I removed some rows to simplify things, but the same technique would apply--wrap all TD contents in a single DIV.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, use `max-height` and `max-width` in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Add a DIV in each TD and add `overflow:hidden` for that element's style and give it fixed dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
    td style="height:xpx; width:xpx; overflow:auto;"
```