# str_replace manipulates html tags

Tags: php, html, str-replace

i wrote a script that search a html content and replace some **keywords** with **linked keyword**

**Code:**

```
$text = '<p>hello</p>
<img src="hello.png" />';

echo str_replace('hello', '<a href="hello">hello</a>', $text);
```

**Result:**

```
<p><a href="hello">hello</a></p>
<img src="<a href="hello">hello</a>.png" />
```

now you can see the src attribute of image is manipulated an i dont want this.

how to exclude **img tag** html tags being searched for replace?

any help will be appreciated

Comment: You could load the HTML into an HTML parser (e.g. DOMDocument) and then scan text based on the tag it is contained in.

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: Never ever use RegEx or simple string replacement to edit HTML. It will fail almost every time. Use a XML parser like e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: Have a look at DOMDocument questions [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485395/php-domdocument). There's loads on Stack Overflow, and very good info in the PHP manual.

Comment: `echo str_replace('<p>hello</p>', '<a href="hello">hello</a>', $text);` however, you'll need to use `preg_replace()` for something more complex or as already stated, a DOMDocument.

Answer (score 1):

**Simpler solution**

```
echo str_replace('<p>hello</p>', '<a href="hello"></a>', $text);
```

**Wide range REGEX solution**

Check this : http://www.thatsquality.com/articles/how-to-match-and-replace-content-between-two-html-tags-using-regular-expressions

**PHPDOM solution**

Check this : http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: What if he has `<p>hello there</p>`?

Comment: my html code is not what i exactly written in question

Comment: He is trying some specific thing. He tries to change hello text with linked one. So if he needs more complex thing like yours then he SHOULD USE REGEX.

Comment: If your HTML code is different then you should share that code with us. REGEX is very tricky and could be changed on every different situations.

Comment: Also you can use PHPDOM as user Reeno said. It's more simpler to understand but has longer lines to write.

Comment: i have a html content with 1000 line. how to share it with you? :)

Comment: I want to help. How can i help you? :)

Comment: i need a code that only search inside <p> tags, not in <img> tags

Comment: Check this : http://www.thatsquality.com/articles/how-to-match-and-replace-content-between-two-html-tags-using-regular-expressions

Answer (score 0):

try regex

```
$text = '<p>hello</p>
<img src="hello.png" />';
echo preg_replace("/hello(?!.(png|jpg))/", "<a href='hello'>here</a>", $text);
```