# Setting table column widths CSS

Tags: html, css

Want to start off by saying I have tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/css-how-to-set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text) with no success, it could be because I am doing it wrong idk...

So I have a 7 column table and my issue is that my 2nd column (TX4200) does not have a `colspan` but the width of that column seems to be bigger than I would like and as a result the other columns are suffering. I am thinking because of the type of layout my table has the auto-width algorithm is having some issues, so I want to try and take this on by brute force.

**Things I have tried**

`table-layout: fixed`

Setting the table `width: 1000px;` but even then the TX column still takes up the most space

`min-width` & `max-width` didn't do anything

**Here is my fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/8Xy24/1/

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Xy24/2/

I just added a `td` width:

```
td {
    width:50px;
}
```

Comment: but that doesn't really make sense... none of the columns are 50px wide...I mean it works, I would still need to fiddle with it a bit but it makes no sense...

Comment: giving a `td` a width is like setting a `min-width` and without that, the `table-layout: fixed` won't really take effect.

Comment: oh okay that makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

You likely want to look at setting either the `overflow` to `hidden` or `word-wrap` to `break-word` in conjunction with the `max-width` for the cells in question depending on the kind of behaviour you want.