# Mix content width and fixed (minimum width) in table

Tags: html, css, width, tablelayout

I want to achieve this:

I have a table for which columns I want to be able to set a fixed width each in px and % (if the content of a cell is larger than specified, the column is allowed to resize). A column I do not set a width for should resize by its content.

I tried this:

1. I set `table-layout` to `fixed`, and used the `width` style on the cells. This works perfectly when I set the `width` of the table as well. But I cannot set the width of the table, since it might shrink columns so that their content overflows.
   Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zdY94/
2. I use `min-width` on the cells, which works only with px values and not with %. The examples are available here: px: http://jsfiddle.net/2bNAz/ %: http://jsfiddle.net/2bNAz/1/

So, is there any possibility of having a table which behaves like `table-layout: auto`, but with the possibility to specify the width for specific columns in px and %?

Answer (score 0):

The second answer offers a workable solution [Set the table column width constant regardless of the amount of text in its cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/css-how-to-set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text)

*Put a div inside the td*. you can set width on the div

```
<td><div style="width: 50px" > blah blah</div></td>
```