# Table width is too much

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

Please have a look at the below code

```
<%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : Feb 7, 2014, 1:03:15 PM
--%>

<%@page import="java.util.Map"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="analyzer.DataHolder"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><center>Web Site Analizer</center></h1>
        <br/>
        <form action=http://localhost:8080/WebSiteAnalizer/SiteAnalizer method=post>
            Enter the Percentage (0-100): <input type="Text" name="percentage">
            <br/><br/><br/>

            Enter the Words (Separated from New Line (/n)): <br/>
            <textarea name='wordList' value='wordList'></textarea>            
            <br/><br/>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>

        <%@page import="java.util.List" %>
        <%@page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
        <%@page import="java.util.HashMap" %>

        <%

            List<DataHolder> dataHolder = (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("list");
            HashMap hashMap = (HashMap)request.getAttribute("wordMap");

            if(hashMap==null)
                               {
                out.println("Hashmap null");
            }

            if(dataHolder!=null && dataHolder.size()>0)
            {
               out.println("</br>");
               out.println("<table border='1'><th>Primary Key</th><th>Original Hash</th><th>Matching Words</th><th>Non Matching words</th>");

                for(int i=0;i<dataHolder.size();i++)
                {
                    DataHolder d = dataHolder.get(i);

                    int primaryKey = d.getPrimaryKey();
                    String originalHash = d.getOriginalHash();
                    ArrayList matchingWords = d.getMatchingWords();
                    ArrayList unMatchingWords = d.getUnmatchingWords();

                    StringBuffer matchingWordsStr = new StringBuffer("");
                    StringBuffer unMatchingWordsStr = new StringBuffer("");

                    //Populating Strings
                    for(int m=0;m<matchingWords.size();m++)
                    {

                        Iterator iter = hashMap.entrySet().iterator();

                        while(iter.hasNext())
                        {
                            Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry)iter.next();

                            if(mEntry.getValue().equals(matchingWords.get(m)))
                            {
                                //out.println(matchingWords.get(m)+" : "+true);
                                matchingWordsStr.append(mEntry.getKey());
                                matchingWordsStr.append(",");
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    for(int u=0;u<unMatchingWords.size();u++)
                    {
                        Iterator iter = hashMap.entrySet().iterator();

                        while(iter.hasNext())
                        {
                            Map.Entry mEntry = (Map.Entry)iter.next();

                            if(mEntry.getValue().equals(unMatchingWords.get(u)))
                            {
                                //out.println(matchingWords.get(m)+" : "+true);
                                unMatchingWordsStr.append(mEntry.getKey());
                                unMatchingWordsStr.append(",");
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    out.println("<tr>");

                    out.println("<td>");
                    out.println(String.valueOf(primaryKey));
                    out.println("</td>");

                    out.println("<td>");
                    out.println(originalHash);
                    out.println("</td>");

                    out.println("<td>");
                    out.println(matchingWordsStr);
                    out.println("</td>");

                    out.println("<td>");
                    out.println(unMatchingWordsStr);
                    out.println("</td>");

                    out.println("</tr>");



                }
               out.println("</table>");
            }

        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code generates a table, but it is really huge, which means the width is too much to fit to the screen. The reason for that is, the `String` values this code enters into the columns are very lengthy. May be 5000 to 10000 words and everything in one column is being displayed in one line. For an example, if "Original Hash" is 10000 characters, then the entire thing is displayed in one line. So is there anyway that I can make the length of this make suit for the screen?

Also please note that I am a developer and not a designer. I very rarely work on scripting languages.

Comment: Can you style the table? e.g. add fixed widths for the columns etc.

Comment: @feitla: Yea, whatever, I just don't know how to.

Answer (score 0):

use this css to break the really long word-

```
td{
   word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How to integrate this into JSP?

Comment: put at your CSS document, or put inside of a `<style>td{word-wrap:break-word;}</style>` remember, style tag must be place inside `<head></head>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You may need to also set the table-layout to fixed see [Set the table column width constant regardless of the amount of text in its cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/css-how-to-set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text). Also for performance you probably want to change it from individual printlns to single a println that takes a string of all your html.