# How to set fixed width long text in detailview yii

Tags: yii

in my yii project i have a gridview an detailview which display stretch over load screen. i have try to modified css style like this detailview

```
array(
    'name'=>'hal_surat',
       'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'max-width:200px;float:left'),
    ),
```

and it in gridview

```
array(
            'header'=>'Perihal',
             'headerHtmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:center;width:240px;max-width:240px'),
            //  'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align:justify;max-width:240px;overflow-x: auto'),\
            'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'white-space: nowrap;')
             'name'=>'hal_surat',
        ),
```

but no one solution. Any one can help me, how to make long text in gridview and detail view can fixed width adjust to width of DIV not stretch over the screen .

Comment: when you look at the html output, do you see your edits? If so, I suggest you check Chrome's element inspector / Firefoxes Firebug (anything that allows you to analyse the code / css) and check where the error may come from...

Comment: and in your gridview code, you're missing a `,` (comma) at the end of the row of `htmlOptions`...

Answer (score 0):

The CSS that will fix the problem for the detail view:

```
table.detail-view {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

table.detail-view td {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;        
}
```

Also you can look here:

- [Set the table column width constant regardless of the amount of text in its cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/css-how-to-set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text)
- [CSS text-overflow in a table cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789723/css-text-overflow-in-a-table-cell)