# Parsing value in Lotus Notes Xpage

Tags: html, css, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a table that pulls values in an xpage in Lotus notes.  I have nowrap set so it doesn't wrap.  Currently the value extends the width of my columns when I set it to nowrap.  However, I don't need to see the whole value that is pulls.  I only need to see if a value is in there.  So I need the column size to remain the same size.  I have tried to use various width values in the xpage.  However, the value still extends the column.  So either I need to parse the value to make it smaller or figure out where to add the width value so it doesn't increase with the variable.

Thanks in advance.

```
<td>
<div>
<xp:text escape="false" style="white-space:nowrap" id="computedFieldStatementNotesDisplay" value="#{auditDoc.StatementNotesDisplay}">
</xp:text>
</div>
</td>
```

Comment: This is a CSS issue. This answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4457905/785061.

Answer (score 1):

Two quick solutions I can think of:

1. use a css overflow statement `overflow: hidden`, `overflow: auto` or maybe `overflow: scroll` and apply this to the containing `<td>` or `<div>` tags; also you might consider setting the table column's width to some value
2. limit the amount of characters displayed in column using SSJS.

JS code could be like this:

```
var limit=20;  //test for max allowable chars
var val=auditDoc.getItemValueString("StatementNotesDisplay");  
if(val.length>limit){
  val=val.left(limit);  
}  
return val;
```

CSS solution might be the preferred one

Update:
Just saw Per's comment linking to a css solution which is quite complete

Answer (score 1):

I want to thank everyone for their response.  I took the information given and applied it.  I had to add the width to the text as well place the settings in the .css.  This is what worked.

I added this to the .css

```
.ellipsis span {
overflow:hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Then inside the xpage I called ellipsis and then set the width in the text area.

```
<td class="ellipsis">
<xp:text escape="false" id="computedFieldStatementNotesDisplay" value="#auditDoc.StatementNotesDisplay}" style="width:100px">
</xp:text>
</td>
```