# CSS table-cell ignores width, even with table-fixed

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'd like to have a `div` with `display: table-cell` that has a percentage width set. `display: table-cell` is my best option I need several side by side `div`s to be equal height.

After researching, I properly set the parent to `display: table; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%` as found in many [other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/css-how-to-set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text), but the `table-cell` still fills the parent.

```css
.table-wrapper {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <div class="table-cell">
    Should be 25%, but it fills .table-wrapper
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this not possible?

Answer (score 5):

You can work around this using a single block element.

```css
.table-wrapper {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <div class="table-cell">
    Should be 25%, but it fills .table-wrapper
  </div>
  <div><div/>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

A  tag will ALWAYS fill it because there is a carriage return on the end of every ...which is pretty sneaky of them to do that w/out any documentation for it! But, nevertheless it's THAT WAY. So, i'd recommend using a tag that does NOT have a carriage return tacked onto the end. Hope that reduces some frustration...i had to learn the hard way!