# Inline-block without line break and with elements into max width

Tags: html, css

Im tried many times to do this, is very usefoul in many situations but seem not possible:

1. Have 2 divs into same div container, in short 2 columns, div container width stay fixed.
2. Every div appear like inline-block, so it adjust based to inner content, so if inner content is nothing, width is zero, if inner is 100px width will be 100px. This is the normal inline-block.
3. The 2 divs must stay **always** in same row, no break line.
4. If content of one or both two divs is overflow, it will be hidden and div stay **always into the width of container**.

Im able to make 1-2-3 but I stop on 4.

This is the code:

```
<div class="container">
       <div class="column">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>                           
       <div class="column">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>                       
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
  display: table;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.column {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

**[Demo](http://liveweave.com/axoIhN)**

Similar thing can be done by inline-block but both 2 ways have same problem: width of div with inner content overflow not stay into container width but stay full content width

Is bit difficoult to explain, hope someone understand.
This is a screenshot of my project, and my problem: http://expirebox.com/download/39f9acff53e75830b1714a653b11e0d0.html

Thank you

Comment: This is as close as I've come. I can't seem to force the table to 100% width. http://liveweave.com/axoIhN

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things to do here:

1. Set `table-layout` to `fixed`:

   ```
   .container {
     width: 200px;
     display: table;
     table-layout: fixed;
     overflow: hidden;
   }
   ```
2. Set `visibility` to hidden in case of *overflow*:

   ```
   var element = document.querySelector('.column');
   if( (element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight) || (element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth)){
     // your element have overflow
     element.style.visibility = "hidden";
   }
   else{
     //your element don't have overflow
   }
   ```

Referred from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/css-how-to-set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/micigenode/2/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: This seems to result in uniform cell widths. Do you have a demo?

Comment: It is probably because of `table-layout: fixed`. However, without it, the width of the `column`s can go beyond the width of `container`.

Comment: Right. Therein lies the problem. :-)