# Limit width on a column using angularjs

Tags: css, css-tables

I am trying to set a max on width using angularjs. I have tried using max-width and also just using width, but it does not seem to stop the column from expanding when ever the specific data pops up. Also, I would like the other columns to stay the way the are. My code looks like this for now:

`<th style="width: 25%;" ng-bind="'column.tab' | i18n"></th>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set the table column width constant regardless of the amount of text in its cells?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text-in-its-cell)