# How to fix a table width

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qltOA.png)Suppose I have a table with two columns

```
<table>

<tr><td>Email</td> <td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Full name</td> <td></td></tr>

</table>
```

I want to fix the table width to a maximum size so that, whatever I write in the second column, the table will not expand more than the fixed size. Rather it will expand its height automatically to keep the big text in its area which is written in the second column. How can this be done?

When I write something big, it looks like the uploaded picture. But I want it to expand vertically, not horizontally.

Comment: Did you really search before posting this question?

Comment: Use max-width css property

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text-in-its-cell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set the table column width constant regardless of the amount of text in its cells?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text-in-its-cell)

Comment: Yes, I searched. Max-width property does not fulfill my requirements. Though I used max-width, the table expands horizontally. But I want it vertically expanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code**

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  max-width:200px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
      }
```

```css
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:100%;
    max-width:200px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.wrapper{
   max-width:200px;
}
table td.last {
    width: 150px;
    word-break: break-all;
    }
table td{
   border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    }  
    
    table td, table th {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: open sans;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #666666;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Email</td> <td class="last">sdfdsffdsfsdfsdf</td></tr>
<tr><td>Full name</td> <td class="last">sdffdsfsdfssssssssssssssssssss</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
   </div>
```

Comment: This is not working. The table keeps expanding horizontally. But what I want is, the table will not expand more than a fixed pixel (something like 200 px). If it needs to expand, it will increase its height.

Comment: Oh, great!! That is what I was searching for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that this:

```css
.table-container {
max-width:800px;
width:100%;
}
.table-container table {
width:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
<table>

<tr><td>Email</td> <td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Full name</td> <td></td></tr>

</table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not working. The table keeps expanding horizontally. But what I want is, the table will not expand more than a fixed pixel (something like 200 px). If it needs to expand, it will increase its height.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Email</td> <td style="max-width: maxSize"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Full name</td > < td style="max-width: maxSize"></td></tr>        
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

please use `style="word-wrap: break-word"` in your td tag

or you can refer this community question.

[Word-wrap in an HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-an-html-table)

Example: Enter Your Values in Second Column.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head> </head>
<body>
  <table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%" style="word-wrap: break-word">
  

 <tr><td>Email</td> <td style="word-wrap: break-word">Hello Column1 Hello Column1 Hello Column1 Hello Column1 Hello Column1 Hello Column1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Full name</td> <td style="word-wrap: break-word">Hello Column</td></tr>

</table>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table >
  <thead class="">
    <tr>
      <th width="60%"></th>
      <th width="20%"></th>
      <th width="20%"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="numeric">Name</th>
      <th class="numeric">Code</th>
      <th class="numeric">Fee</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```