# Making the widths of columns in a "floating" table header fixed

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a **floating** HTML `table header`, which remains at the top when the table is being scrolled through. I have implemented in by cloning the header of the original table and then hiding / showing it based on the scroll position.

When my table had a few columns, the "floating-header" had the same column width as the columns in the original table, due to this code:

```
$headerClone.children().outerWidth(function(i,val){
    return $headerGrandChildren.eq(i).outerWidth(true);
});
```

However, now that the table has more columns and goes over the page right margin, the "floating-header" width is being adjusted and squeezed, disregarding the set `width=x` style element and the `table-layout: fixed;` CSS, see screenshot:

[image]

I have read that `"The browser will then set column widths based on the width of cells in the first row of the table"` in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text-in-its-cell).

**Question:** how to best set the fixed size of the "floating-header"? Should I create an invisible row that would accompany the "fixed-header" so it would not resize as soon as my table is wider than the page?

Comment: It would be a heck of a lot easier just to use `position: fixed` to ensure your header stays at the top of the page. Also, if you insist on using tables, I'd also recommend setting a `max-width` of `100%` to prevent it from needing a horizontal scroll.

Comment: You can use this plugin or get the idea from it: https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders

Comment: Can you show simplified html part of your table?

Comment: @ObsidianAge - when I add the `possition: fixed` to the `<thead>` the header does not look like part of the table anymore, the widths of each column is not the same as for the table itself.

Comment: Woah, you shouldn't be using a `<table>` at *all* for a "header", and you certainly shouldn't be adding the `position` property to the `<thead>` element. It would go on the `<div>` used to *contain* the `<table>`. I'd recommend avoiding table-based layouts entirely if at all possible, as they're not built for responsiveness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the logic to copy not only the header (for it to become a fixed header) but also the first row, since: `"The browser will then set column widths based on the width of cells in the first row of the table"`.

```
.append($tbodyFirstRowClone.css('visibility', 'collapse'))
```

And used:

```
position: sticky;
```

It solves the issue for my usecase. Specifically:

- There was no use for responsiveness in my case;
- `position: fixed;` is not sideways-scroll-able so I can't use it;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
$('table, td, th, thead').width(function() {    
    return $(this).width();
});

$('td, th').height(function() { 
    return $(this).height();
});

$('table, thead').css('display','block')
```