# How do I change the columns widths of this html table

Tags: html, css, html-table

### Is there a way to specify column width here?

Hi, I'm trying to style a table, but I don't know how to specify column width. I've  read that the way to do it is by using CSS: `<td style="width:130px">`

I'm using xampp and I only use a PHP file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>$item</td>
      <td><img src='item_image_folder/img'></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

***what the table looks like***

```
Category 1

item_name  image
item_name  image

Category 2

item   image 
item   image 

Category 3

long_item_name   image
```

Comment: `I've read that the way to do it is by using css: td style="width:130px"` The way to do it is to use CSS, in a `<style>` / stylesheet, *not* to put it in your HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set the table column width constant regardless of the amount of text in its cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text-in-its-cell)

Comment: Do you have a stylesheet/.css file? If not create one [and learn what it stand for](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
td {
   width:130px;
}
</style>
```

this is using `css` styling, specifying the width for the `<td>`'s

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th width="200"></th>
        <th width="100"></th>
        <th width="100"></th>
     </tr>
</table>
```

You can put width attribute with pixel / % format.
(example: width="50")
(example: width="50%")

Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_width.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all you'd need to do is select the cell(s) you want to widen, then set this attribute in your `<td>` tag: `width="40px"` (example only - change it however you like). You can also change height in the same way, with the `height="20px"` attribute.

Comment: D'you think it's better?

Comment: Yes since your answer is a duplicate I won't upvote it but, I'm removing my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in styling each `<td>`'s width within an echo statement. The solution was to simply use single quotes instead of double quotes

`<td width='130px'>$item</td>` *this one was correct inside of echo"";*

`<td width="130px">$item</td>`

I could also use `<td id='cell1'>$item</td>` and and style with:

`<style>
    td#cell1{width:130px;}
</style>`

Comment: Use a specific CSS file, it's a better way to stylize a web page