# Why does table need width:0 to respect column widths?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

This table has column widths 59px and 100px, even though 50px and 100px are the specified column widths.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

col:first-child {
  width: 50px;
}

col:nth-child(2) {
  width: 100px;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column A</th>
      <th>Column B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But if I add `width: 0` to the table, it works.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 0;
}

col:first-child {
  width: 50px;
}

col:nth-child(2) {
  width: 100px;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column A</th>
      <th>Column B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Why is setting `width: 0` necessary? Is there a better way to do it?>

Comment: Use for `<th>`  `word-break: break-word;` to break words

Comment: @Observer, but I don't necessarily want to break words. The latter example does not break words.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set the table column width constant regardless of the amount of text in its cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text-in-its-cell)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `max-width` property to the `<th>` element. Also, you need to specify `box-sizing: border-box;` to `<th>` and `<td>` elements to include padding and border

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th:first-child {
  max-width: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

th:nth-child(2) {
  max-width: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column A</th>
      <th>Column B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

[CSS 2.2 Section 17.5.2.1 Fixed table layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#fixed-table-layout) says:

> The table's width may be specified explicitly with the 'width' property. A value of 'auto' (for both 'display: table' and 'display: inline-table') means use the automatic table layout algorithm.¹

Width's initial value is auto and the user-agent style sheet does change this for table elements. So despite the css being `table-layout: fixed`, the automatic table layout algorithm is used, not the fixed table layout algorithm. Setting the width to something else forces the fixed table layout algorithm to be used.

There isn't an obviously "better" solution to this.

---

<sub>¹ It then goes on to say that browsers don't *have* to do this, but it seems they do anyway</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can take a look at [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break).

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

col:first-child {
  width: 50px;
}

col:nth-child(2) {
  width: 100px;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  word-break:break-word;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column A</th>
      <th>Column B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```