# Setting width of HTML table header elements via JavaScript not updating

Tags: javascript, html, css, width

I have an HTML table, and since the table headings (`<th>`) automatically set their own width based on the width of table data (`<td>`), I am trying to add `10px` to whatever value it sets.

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("th")).forEach(th => {
    th.style.width = `${parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(th).getPropertyValue("width").split("px")[0]) + 10}px`;
});
```

Logging my starting and ending width works fine, everything is normal (ie: `"14px"` to `"24px"`), the values do get set, as seen in the Chrome Dev Tools, but the actual table on the webpage doesn't update. I tried editing the values via Chrome Dev Tools to large numbers like `1000px` and `100%`, but that did nothing. Am I missing something?

Note: I'm using Electron, latest, on Windows, latest (but *I would assume* this is a problem with my general HTML code and doesn't have to do with how Electron works).

Comment: Does table-layout:fixed help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text-in-its-cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could increase 10px in each 'th' using CSS style, setting the padding of the element.

```
<style>
th { padding: 0px 10px; }
</style>
```

---

If your table is setting to 100% width, and you increase the width of all elements, you will not see the difference, no matter how many pixels you are using to do this.