# How to force Vuetify to use fixed table header widths?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Based on a configuration file I'm calculating table header rowspans and colspans dynamically. The configuration file also provides fixed widths for table headers without child headers. I want to use a Vuetify table for this and tried the following code ( [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) )

```
<template>
  <v-table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th :colspan="5">usability</th>
        <th :colspan="3">risk management</th>
        <th>back to usability</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 220px">user tasks</th>
        <th style="width: 200px">subtasks</th>
        <th style="width: 200px">usescenarios</th>
        <th style="width: 220px">usescenario tasks</th>
        <th style="width: 250px">useerrors</th>
        <th style="width: 220px">sequence of events</th>
        <th style="width: 220px">risks</th>
        <th style="width: 220px">risk control measures</th>
        <th style="width: 220px">system requirements</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td v-for="index in 9" :key="index">
          <span
            >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
            nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
            erat, sed diam voluptua.</span
          >
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </v-table>
</template>
```

Having a look at the column widths you can see that the first column should have a width of 220px. The HTML and CSS confirms that. But the actual rendered width is ~109px.

How can I tell Vuetify to use the expected widths?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `min-width` CSS property over the table body, and column tag.

[Demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

```css
<style>
  .v-table .v-table__wrapper table tbody tr td:nth-child(2) {
    min-width: 260px;
  }
</style>
```

Change the `nth-child` count to select desired column.

### Update

If you get the heights from configuration files, then again, `min-height` does the job.

```js
    ...
      <tr>
        <th style="min-width: 200px">user tasks</th>
    ...
```

[Demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)
Or,

```js
<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  const col3Width = ref('250px')
</script>
<style>
  .v-table .v-table__wrapper table tbody tr td:nth-child(3) {
    min-width: v-bind(col3Width);
  }
</style>
```

[Demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Style bindings should serve for dynamic usage.

Comment: sorry, this is not what I'm looking for. The column widths are coming from a configuration file

Comment: okay so I should replace `width` with `min-width`. Would you mind explaining why? I would expect `width` to come up with the same result

Comment: It's because of the table layout which do not act on `width`. [Detailed discussions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457506/set-the-table-column-width-constant-regardless-of-the-amount-of-text-in-its-cell)